# Continuously checking status on Serial Port

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am having some issues with a serial application I am developing with QT.

I need to continuously output a command via serial to get back a reply from the controller im working with -- (motor position, motor speed, etc).

It looks something like this:

```
void MainWindow::updateMCTarRotvalues()
{
      HANDLE RS232Handle;
      RS232Handle=OpenRS232(MotorControlCommPortSelection(), 9600);
      SendCmd(RS232Handle, 1, 6, 3, 5, 0); //motor 5 get speed
      auto result = GetResult(RS232Handle);
      QString AddressOutCS = QString::number(result.address);
      QString GuessOutCS = QString::number(result.guess);
      QString StatusOutCS = QString::number(result.status);
      QString ValueOutCS = QString::number(result.value);
      CloseRS232(RS232Handle);

      RS232Handle=OpenRS232(MotorControlCommPortSelection(), 9600);
      SendCmd(RS232Handle, 1, 6, 3, 4, 0); //motor 4 get speed
      auto result2 = GetResult(RS232Handle);
      QString AddressOutCS2 = QString::number(result.address);
      QString GuessOutCS2 = QString::number(result.guess);
      QString StatusOutCS2 = QString::number(result.status);
      QString ValueOutCS2 = QString::number(result.value);
      CloseRS232(RS232Handle);
}
```

Then I use the QString variables to print the data I am after.

I have come up with a solution to use a QTimer to call the function:

```
QTimer *timer2 = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer2, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateMCTarRotvalues()));
timer2 -> start();
```

This actually works well for one motor, but now when I wanna call another motors parameters I get mixing of the variables. Meaning sometimes AddressOutCS is not of motor 5 but of motor 4.  If this makes sense. Its like the function is being asynchronously run and mixing happens.

I hope I explained my problem well enough to get some help. Let me know if it is not clear.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Seems like the problem is with the data being sent? If it is mixed by the time the program sees it then there doesn't seem to be much you can do. Do you have any control over how the data is sent?

Comment: Well I am just using some C code that came with the controller. I actually posted another question on here to convert it to use QSerial. Think that would help?

Comment: Perhaps a mutex could be introduced to ensure that only one set of parameters is sent at a time?

Comment: Any other ideas? I tried to put some delays and whatnot in there, but nothing really seems to work. I dont really want to convert everything to use the QSerial integration, as I am not even sure if that will work.

Comment: The idea to continuously open and close the serial port is wrong. This can take a very long time, is blocking, and you're not supposed to behave that way. You should have the `QSerialPort` instance open and ready for commands.